# check if matrixs elements are all not equal or deferent elements

Tags: matlab

I have the following vector `v = [r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 .... rn]`, with `r` integer numbers.

I want to check:

if `r1` not equal to `r2` not equal to `r3` ... not equal to `rn` (all different of each other):
   print v

else (some elements are equal and other not equal):
   print the index of the equal elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the `unique` command. It will return the values of all unique values.

If you want to check that all values in your matrix `v` are unique, I would use the following command:

```
everything_is_unique = length(unique(v))==length(v);
```

You can also return the indices of the equal elements.
See [the documentation on `unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) for more information.

Comment: You meant `everything_is_unique = length(unique(v))==length(v); ? because you compared between vector and scalar.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate to using unique you can also sort the elements and check whether they are all different:

```
all(diff(sort(v)))
```

By using sort with more input arguements you could get the indices you are looking for.

Comment: Note that this should outperform a loop, for short vectors. For very long ones a loop may be faster.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give one more solution, and a comparison of all methods tried so far.

My solution is based on the observation that when using builtin functions like `sort()` or `unique()`, you lose opportunities for early escapes. That is, the `sort()` will have to sort the vector *completely* before you can continue with your algorithm, even though this is not required if two equal values are already detected inside the `sort`.

Therefore, I simply iterate through the array, and compare the current value to all following values using `any()`. This works around some of these issues, and works well enough for a lot of cases.

However, the worst case complexity is **O(N²)**, which is a hell of a lot worse than `sort()`, which has only **O(N·log(N))**. So as usual, it all depends on context :)

Trying this:

```
clc

N = 1e4;

% Zigzag's solution
tic
for ii = 1:1e2
    v = randi(N, N,1);
    length(unique(v))==length(v);
end
toc


% Dennis Jaheruddin's solution 
tic
for ii = 1:1e4
    v = randi(N, N,1);
    all(diff(sort(v)));
end
toc

% My solution 
tic
for ii = 1:1e4
    v = randi(N, N,1);
    cond = true;
    for jj = 1:numel(v)
        if any(v(jj) == v(jj+1:end))
            cond = false; 
            break; 
        end
    end
end
toc
```

The random numbers are generated inside the loops to ensure a variety of different cases will come by. Results on my PC:

```
Elapsed time is 16.787976 seconds.  % unique
Elapsed time is 14.284696 seconds.  % sort + diff
Elapsed time is  5.376655 seconds.  % loop + any
```

So explicit looping (provided `feature accel` is on) with early exit is actually almost three times faster than the standard "vectorized" approach :)

PS - I also tried to nest *another* loop to try and improve having to compare *all* value before detecting equal values (first `v(jj)==v(jj+1:end)` is evaluated completely, before `any()` can start doing its job), but here, the overheads really start to get in the way (or the JIT is not coping well enough with this sort of thing, I don't know). In theory, this should be even faster of course, but unfortunately, not in MATLAB :)

However, change the random number generation

```
v = randi(N, N,1);
```

into

```
v = randi(N*N, N,1);
```

and the results are quite different:

```
Elapsed time is 0.162625 seconds.   % unique
Elapsed time is 0.147369 seconds.   % sort + diff
Elapsed time is 30.767247 seconds.  % loop + any
```

Here I used only 100 iterations instead of 10.000, for obvious reasons :)